# Launching Python Script With Arguments In VS Community

Tags: python, visual-studio

**Context:**

Working in Visual Studio Community 2019, developping a Python script which needs arguments (a figure between 1 and 3).

So, I configured the debugger to do so like this:
[image]

In my Python script, i tried to print this argument:

`print(str(date.today()) + " Argument Value :" + str(sys.argv))`

**Issue:**

I got this in the console:

> Argument Value: ['PathTo\MyScriptName.py', '1']

How should i do to get only the argument without the path of the script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.argv[1].  sys.argv is a list. You should check that it has 2 (or more) elements first, but sys.argv[0] will always be the path of your script.